# Prove that $2^n \ge n^3 \ \forall n\ge 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

$$2^n \ge n^3  \ \forall n\ge 1$$
My effort:

1. Check the base case: $P(1): 2\ge1 \ \text{(true)}$
2. supposing that $P(n) \Rightarrow  P(n+1):$ $2^{n+1} \ge (n+1)^3$
3. I'll try the induction step:
   $$2^{n+1} = 2^n \cdot 2 \ge 2n^3 = n^3 \cdot 2 \ge n^3 \cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)^3}$$
   I'm not sure about the last step, but in any case, I can't find any way to get to $(n+1)^3$ and prove the induction step.

How can I do?

Comment: What is the idea behind dividing by $(n+1)^3$ in your last step? As it was noted below, you can prove this for $n\geq 10$. Just simply show that $2n^3  \ge (n + 1)^3$ for $n\geq 10$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot prove that since it is false when $n=2$. It is true when $n\geqslant10$ though. Indeed, $2^{10}=1024>1000=10^3$, and, if $2^n\geqslant n^3$, then, as you have proved, $2^{n+1}\geqslant2n^3$. And $2n^3\geqslant(n+1)^3$, since$$2n^3\geqslant(n+1)^3\iff2\geqslant\left(1+\frac1n\right)^3,$$which is true, since $n\geqslant10$, and therefore$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^3\leqslant\left(\frac{11}{10}\right)^2<2.$$

Comment: But the induction step could still be proved right?

Comment: Of course not. The statement is true when $n=1$. So, if the induction step could be proved for every $n$, then the statement would hold for every $n$.

Comment: if it is $n\ge 10 $ then we can close it as duplicate of this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772026/use-induction-to-prove-that-2n-gt-n3-for-every-integer-n-ge-10

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore ok

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I got it, thanks!